# Universal App View Controller Main Window

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I just started playing with universal apps, and im a bit confused it appears there are 3 app delegates one main and 2 that are subclasses of it, but my problem is where do i put the code that will let me setup UITabBarControllers and add functionality to the first view, im sure its simple but its eluding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming there is one parent for shared functionality, and 2 subclasses to represent custom behavior of the iPhone, or iPad so... if it is code that you want to be executed for both iPhone and iPad, then you will put the code in the parent, or if it is specialized, put it in the appropriate child class.

also make sure that you are calling the super method for each of the delegate methods.

Comment: Im not sure why there are three, i just created a new project from scratch and thats how it was, it doesnt look like any code in the "iPhone" app delegate is even getting executed.

Comment: how did you set up the new project (what version of xcode, and what type did you select)? do you have more than one target?

Comment: Xcode 4.0 just selected Window Based Application and just one target.

Comment: Yeah I looked it over, that is exactly what is happening.

Comment: so do you know why it doesnt seem to want to fire anything in the AppDelegate? i put `NSLog(@"hit");` in the applicationDidFinishLaunching method just to test and it never fired, i tried every one of the delegates.

Comment: are you calling the super method?

Comment: like: `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSLog(@"iphone");
    return [super application: application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    
    
}`